# How to show product category on product page in magento2.2.6?

Tags: magento2.2.6, product-page

How to show product category on product page in magento2.2.6?
i selected `2columns-left.xml` layout template in category.
[http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/shop.html](http://www.gsmalhi.com/wedding/shop.html)
i want to add sidebar on this page please check above content http://prntscr.com/lczbxh.
Please explain step by step.

Comment: First url is not working.

Comment: ohh sorry, please check this http://magento-213836-648260.cloudwaysapps.com/shop.html

Comment: Ok its working. Now you want to show only those categories which are associated with this products in the left sidebar. Right?

Comment: yes i want to show categories in left side bar.

Comment: Check my answer. Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module with name **STech_Procategories** by following steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under

> app/code/STech/Procategories/registration.php

with below content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Procategories',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Procategories/etc/module.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Procategories" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **catalog_product_view.xml** under

> app/code/STech/Procategories/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="pro.categories" template="STech_Procategories::sidebar/categories.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **categories.phtml** under

> app/code/STech/Procategories/view/frontend/templates/sidebar/categories.phtml

with below content:

```
<?php
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$_product = $block->getProduct();
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$_categories = $categoryCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $categoryIds);
?>

<?php if(count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="content">
            <dl class="options">
                <dt><?=  __('Product Categories') ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ol class="items">
                        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                            <?php if ($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                                <li class="item">
                                    <a href="<?= $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?= $_category->getName() ?></a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ol>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Run setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy.

Comment: After complete this steps then?

Comment: Thats it now test the product page. Don't forget to run setup upgrade, di compile,  and static content deploy. That's it.

Comment: when i put this all steps then my magento admin stop working.

Comment: i want to call default sidebar of magento 2.2

Comment: These code never affect your admin.

Comment: please check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/ld1qea and let me know how we can fix this issue.

Comment: These error something different which is not related the module I have shared. Javascript errors are showing but I have not used any javascript in my module. Please check your other module or permissions of pub directory.